# Scanning the next line, but only to a certain length

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, maxlength

I have an existing code, where I have to scan the next sentence that the user types into the console. This sentence can be no longer than 99 characters. My current code takes the `.nextLine()` method, and saves whatever was typed, in a String. Than it checks the length of that String, if it's above 99, I use the `.substring(0,99)` method to cut off the excess. This works just fine, but I find it really ugly.

The problem is that if, let's say, a user would decide to copy-paste both volumes of Lev Tolstojs *War and Peace* into the console, my program would first try to save that as a String for no reason whatsoever, as I only need the first 99 characters. The question arises: Is there a way to tell the scanner to stop scanning after a certain number of characters? It would be cheaper, than scanning everything and than only using the part I need.

Comment: "Cheaper" in what practical sense? How likely is it that any user will copy/paste war and peace? If you have code which already works, have you consider the cost of more complex code (both writing and maintaining) vs any actual benefit?

Comment: `nextLinet().substring(0, 99)` no?

Comment: Jon, I cannot consider something that I do not know, how can I consider the complexity of a code if I don't know if it even exists. I'm learning this programming language,  so for all I know, this could be done very easily. I asked for an alternative for my code, once I have one, sure I will consider if using it is actually worth it or not. Also this is a coding exercise the likelyhood of any user typing in anything at all, other than me for testing is 0. Our user in this case is hypothetical and War and Peace is obviously just an exaggeration, but I would still like an answear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... I have an existing code, where I have to scan the next sentence that the user types into the console. This sentence can be no longer than 99 characters. ..."*

This answer is similar to *@RifatRubayatulIslam*'s answer.

Utilize the *[read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#read(char%5B%5D))* method, providing a *char* array with a length of *99*.
The *new-line delimiter* will be included here, you can use *[String#trim](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim())*, or *[String#stripTrailing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripTrailing())*, to remove it.

```java
try (Reader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in)) {
    char[] a = new char[99];
    int n = r.read(a);
    String s = new String(a, 0, n).stripTrailing();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using [Reader#read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read-char:A-) method. Here is an example using `BufferedReader`.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a buffered reader for System.in
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            char[] buffer = new char[99]; // Define the buffer of appropriate size
            System.out.print("Enter text: ");
            int n = br.read(buffer); // Read user input in the buffer,
                                    // n denotes number of characters read 
            String input = new String(buffer, 0, n); // Create string upto n character
            System.out.println(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The buffer would also contain the newline character if input is less than buffer size. You might want to strip it.

Comment: While this is unlikely to occur in practice, as per spec this isn't guaranteed - `read(buffer)` does not promise it'll fetch all 99. Also, the exception handling is bad (just make `main` `throws Exception` - less code, cleaner stack traces, it's win-win). This also reads potentially _the next_ line, which clearly wasn't intended.